# How to get the folder name where web app deployed in java?

Tags: java, tomcat

In our production environment, we have Tomcat configured to such that in the webapps directory there is a symlink which point to the .war file deployed elsewhere on the server, like so:

```
tomcat 7.0.53
|_webapps
  |_app1 (symlinks to /usr/local/myCompany/app1.war)
  |_app2 (symlinks to /usr/local/myCompany/app2.war)
```

etc.

All the apps are built from the same code base and when I build it, I specify whether or not it's app1 or app2.  I have been given the task of determining whether it's app1 or app2 at tomcat startup time instead, so now all the symlinks will go point at the same file.

Is there any way to tell what symlink is pointing to that file programmatically in the StartupContextListener?  It should expand the war once for each app, shouldn't it?

This is how server.xml is configured for each app:

```
  <Host name="www.app1.com" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false">
     <Context path="" docBase="/usr/local/mpl/tomcat/webapps/app1" />
     <Alias>www.app1.com</Alias>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="www.app1.com_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
  </Host>
```

If I could get access to the docBase attribute or to the name attribute of the Host tag, it could solve the problem that way, but I am not sure if I can get that info.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Extremely unlikely.  The symlink de-reference and indirection is handled at the operating system level.  Tomcat knows it followed a symlink when loading the war as it knows the type of the file, but by the time your app loads tomcat has likely discarded that information.  Make a simple webapp that dumps the full contents of the system properties and you'll know what info you have to work with.  Note that this is an implementation detail of the tomcat version you are running and doesn't provide a stable api to access that data.

Comment: Does [getContextPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath%28%29) not work, here? If `app1.war` and `app2.war` both point to the same real file, you should be able to programmatically detect at runtime the context name and infer which deployment you're running.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't use getContextPath here.